# En mi código no siempre guarda los datos en la BD pero si envia el correo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, email

requiero de su colaboración en mi siguiente caso:
Poseo el siguiente código

```
<?php } else {

$query = "INSERT INTO pedidos (id, usuario, monto, nro_transf, banco_emisor, banco_destino, fecha_transf, ci_nro_cuenta, status_pedido) 
VALUES(null, '$user', '$monto', '$nro_transf', '$banco_emisor', '$banco_destino', '$fecha_transf', '$ci_nro_cuenta', '$status_pedido')";

    $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $query) or mysqli_error($db); 
        $_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  = "Se ha registrado su pedido de manera Exitosa.<br>";

        $email = $_SESSION['user']['email'];
        $nombre = $_SESSION['user']['nombre'];
        $asunto = "ASUNTO";
        $cuerpo = "Hola $nombre <br><br>
        CONTENIDO DEL CORREO.";
        enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo); 
        $_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  .= '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Hemos enviado Un correo con el resumen de su pedido';

        }
```

En mi codigo despues de efectuar unas validaciones requiero que se ejecuten 2 acciones:

1. Que se guarden los datos en mi base de datos MySQL
2. Y que se envíe un correo electrónico al usuario.

Resulta que en muchas oportunidades no se ejecuta la sentencia de ingresar los datos a la Base de Datos pero si envía el correo electronico, y me gustaria saber si existe alguna manera de efectuar una validación por ejemplo:
Si se ejecuta de manera correcta el INSERT entonces se envíe el correo electrónico.
Agradezco su valiosa orientación al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes modificarlo para que se condicione el envío sólo `mysqli_query($db, $query)` se evalúa como verdadero, algo  así:

```
<?php } else {

$query = "INSERT INTO pedidos (id, usuario, monto, nro_transf, banco_emisor, banco_destino, fecha_transf, ci_nro_cuenta, status_pedido) 
VALUES(null, '$user', '$monto', '$nro_transf', '$banco_emisor', '$banco_destino', '$fecha_transf', '$ci_nro_cuenta', '$status_pedido')";


   // $resultado_ingreso = mysqli_query($db, $query) or mysqli_error($db); 
    if (mysqli_query($db, $query)){
        $_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  = "Se ha registrado su pedido de manera Exitosa.<br>";

        $email = $_SESSION['user']['email'];
        $nombre = $_SESSION['user']['nombre'];
        $asunto = "ASUNTO";
        $cuerpo = "Hola $nombre <br><br>
        CONTENIDO DEL CORREO.";
        enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo); 
        $_SESSION['msn_pedidos']  .= '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Hemos enviado Un correo con el resumen de su pedido';
    } else {
        // o hacer lo que estimes pertinente cuando ocurre un error
        die(mysqli_error($db));
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por su gentil respuesta, implementare inmediatamente su sugerencia, pero me parece que haria lo mismo es decir si ocurriera un error en el INSERT igual enviaria el correo al usuario..! no se es la logica que yo logro determinar desde mi perspectiva..!

Comment: perdón me faltaron los paréntesis en el die. En esta propuesta el mail se enviará sólo si if (mysqli_query($db, $query))  se evalúa/ejecuta como verdadero, de lo contrario pasa directo al else a ejecutar el die o algún retorno que estimes para el caso de error  .. esa es la gracia del if/else..  no es lo mismo, tú código asigna un valor a la variable $resultado_ingreso si se ejecuta ok o (or) si falla (en ambos casos) además nunca se utiliza para condicionar más abajo... básicamente eso es lo que te falta un if que condicione el envío, saludos!

Comment: para comprobarlo puedes forzar un error en el sql, ej. cambiar el nombre de la tabla a una tabla inexistente

Comment: Perfecto, Gracias

Comment: excelente....!!